# XSLT:Recursive Mapping

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT transformation and got stuck with this recursive mapping.

```
<Element1>
  <Element11/>
  <Element12/>
  <Element13/>
  <Element1>
     <Element11/>
     <Element12/>
     <Element13/>
  </Element1>
</Element1>
```

Will be transformed into

```
<Information>
 <Element11/>
 <Element12/>
 <Element13/>
</Information>
<!-- This will be the child Element1 -->
<Metadata>
 <Element11/>
 <Element12/>
 <Element13/>
</Metadata>
```

Definitely I can't use:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:for-each select="Element1">
                <Information>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Is your expected output definitely correct, as it is not well-formed XML (It does not have a single root element), or should the **Metadata** element be a child of the **Imformation** element?

Comment: Yes. The output is correct. `Metadata` is outside of `Information` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Copy everything -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Template handling the top-level 'Element1' -->
  <xsl:template match="Element1">
    <Information>
      <!-- Apply the copy template to all sub-elements except 'Element1' -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name()!='Element1']"/>
    </Information>
    <!-- Apply the templates to the 'Element1' sub-elements -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Element1"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Template handling the inner 'Element1' -->
  <xsl:template match="Element1/Element1">
    <Metadata>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Metadata>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As Tim notes the result is not a valid XML because it has two root elements. To generate an extra `root` element to make the output valid XML add this template:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
    <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
  </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks. I gonna test it shortly. Two parallel nodes are not a problem because they are inside a root node.

Comment: Didn't get the transformation for `inner Element1`. Error says that `ERROR:  'The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.'`. If it is because of the missing root then a phony root element `<Element>` can be added. But where would I put that?

Comment: Yes, I think that the problem is the multiple root. See expanded answer for a possible solution