# how to add child elements

Tags: xml, xslt

It is reverse mapping of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895418/xsltrecursive-mapping/).
Here I am trying to transform

```
<Information>
 <Element11/>
 <Element12/>
 <Element13/>
</Information>
<!-- This will be the child Element1 -->
<Metadata>
 <Element11/>
 <Element12/>
 <Element13/>
</Metadata>
<Metadata>
 <Element11/>
 <Element12/>
 <Element13/>
</Metadata>
```

To:

```
<Element1>
  <Element11/>
  <Element12/>
  <Element13/>
  <Element1>
     <Element11/>
     <Element12/>
     <Element13/>
  </Element1>
  <Element1>
     <Element11/>
     <Element12/>
     <Element13/>
  </Element1>
</Element1>
```

I tried using `or` at the root but it didn't work.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Information | Metadata">
 <Element1>
 <!-- Rest of the elements -->
  <xsl:for-each select="Metadata">
   <Element1>
   <!-- Rest of the elements -->
   </Element1>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </Element1>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know the sense of this example but the following code should produce the desired output ... but it's not the only possible way to solve it :-D

```
<xsl:template match="Information">
  <Element1>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <!-- if the elements contains values -->
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="../Metadata">
      <Element1>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
          <xsl:copy>
            <!-- if the elements contains values -->
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Element1>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Element1>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is called recursive binding. Thank you. I am going to test it soon.

Comment: There is one more doubt as I am new to XSLT. The example xml I gave above does not have any value in it. But if I have any value in the element `<xsl:copy/>` just copies the xml elements. How can I copy it with values?

Comment: @Himanshu Yadav: I modifed the example to copy also a simple text value. If there are sub elements it becomes a bit more tricky. Then '<xsl:apply-templates>' is the way it goes on. Usually you can choose between the iterative way (like the example above) or the declarative way with templates and xsl:apply-templates.

Answer (score 1):

Another very similar way, assumes that the input is well-formed (wrapped in some element) :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/SomeElement">
    <Element1>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Information/*"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="Metadata">
            <Element1>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            </Element1>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Element1>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```