# XSLT Template: Just copying the child elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT transformation.
It is the extension of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895418/xsltrecursive-mapping). Right now I am copying all the nodes like this and then transforming them as per the answer of the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895418/xsltrecursive-mapping).

```
<!-- Copy everything -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

But input has two parent elements.

```
<Parent1>
  <Parent11>
    <Element1>
    <!--Rest of the xml I want to work with-->
    </Element1>
   <Parent11>
  <Parent21>
   <Other></Other>
  </Parent21>
<Parent1>
```

I tried using

```
<xsl:template match="Element1">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

But then it returned me xml values in plain text. With the values of `<Parent21>` children.
Based on the answer I tried

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Parent1/Parent11/Element1"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
```

And this returned me nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to process the Element1 then keep the usual identity template

```
<!-- Copy everything -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and add another template for `/`:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Parent1/Parent11/Element1"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This will "skip" straight to Element1 and continue normal processing from there, ignoring the rest of the document. You can then use other templates matching nodes inside Element1 to do whatever other processing you need.

If there's more than one Element1 in your document then you'll need to wrap a root element around them to make the output well formed, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Parent1/Parent11/Element1"/>
  </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Where would I use it? At the end of the transformation I will be having more than one `Element1`.